# Ordre des adjectifs en français

Tags: grammaire

Il semble qu'en anglais l'ordre d'un groupe d'adjectif soit bien spécifique:

> “Adjectives in English absolutely have to be in this order: opinion-size-age-shape-colour-origin-material-purpose Noun. So you can have a lovely little old rectangular green French silver whittling knife. But if you mess with that word order in the slightest you’ll sound like a maniac. It’s an odd thing that every English speaker uses that list, but almost none of us could write it out.”

Est-ce qu'il existe une règle similaire en français ?

Comment: You sound like maniac in French if you use so many adjectives  : **un joli petit vieux couteau français rectangulaire vert argenté coupant*. You could say though : *un joli petit couteau français ancien, rectangulaire, vert, argenté et coupant* !

Comment: L'affirmation de Forsyth est [discutable](https://www.latimes.com/socal/burbank-leader/tn-blr-me-aword-20160914-story.html).

Comment: @XouDo note that I'd say "*en argent*" (material) rather than "*argenté*" (colour) in this context

Comment: @Rafalon oui et "d'argent" pourrait convenir aussi!

Answer (score 0):

La Wikipédia française ([Adjectifs en anglais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif#Adjectifs_en_anglais)) est d'accord avec ce que @dargaud a écrit. Mais elle ne dit rien d'une règle similaire en français, donc on suppose qu'une telle règle n'existe pas. Quand même, n'est-il pas le cas que certains ordres semblent plus naturelles que d'autres ?

Comment: Non seulement il existe des règles pour l'ordre de l'adjectif en français mais il y a même un [article de Wikipedia en français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l%27adjectif_en_fran%C3%A7ais) sur le sujet.

Comment: Merci, @None; mais cet article ne dit rien au sujet de la question qui concerne l'ordre de plusieurs adjectifs (soit postposés soit antéposés) basé sur leurs sens. Il ne dit que les règles sur un changement de position, postposé où antéposé, basé sur le sens de l'adjectif.

Comment: Le cas de plusieurs adjectifs est traité dans le chapitre sur la syntaxe qui se termine par  « En conclusion, en cas de pluralité d'épithètes d'un même nom, placées du même côté de ce nom, la coordination ne sera possible que si ces différentes épithètes peuvent être ressenties comme des éléments parallèles. ».

Comment: Je ne sais pas ce qu'il signifie. Pouvez-vous l'expliquer, svp ?